# In Windows 10 using Microsoft Edge when viewing a PDF how can you navigate to a specific page number?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

In Windows 10 using **Microsoft Edge** when viewing a **PDF** how can you navigate to a specific **page number**?

I understand that I can scroll up and down. What I would like to do is know if there is a way to enter a specific page number and jump right to that page. 
For example I enter in page # 49 and Edge goes to page 49 instead of scrolling down 49 pages. 
Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is feature has been added in the 1511 update (November 2015) update for Windows 10. Microsoft Edge now shows a toolbar when scrolling through PDF files. On the left side of the toolbar is the ability to jump to a specific page number.

[image: PDF Toolbar in Microsoft Edge]